# Updating n:m relationship without much overhead

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, entity-framework-5

I got an n:m relationship between these three tables: `Products`, `Keywords` and `ProductKeywords`

Now everytime I update a `Product`, I provide a `List<Keyword>` with the **new** chosen keywords. This collection can contain Keywords that are already chosen as the product keywords, as well as new or removed ones. Now I want to update this in my database.

For now I'm clearing the entire `ProductKeywords` table where `ProductKeywords.ProductId` equals `Product.Id`. Of course this produces **very much** overhead as it clears out any keywords for a specific product.

Is there an easy way to update this n:m relationship without clearing the entirety of the products keywords before? So it should remove ProductKeywords that are not present in the new `List<Keyword>` collection anymore but still in the table, as well as add new ProductKeywords that are not present in the table yet, but in the `List<Keyword>`. All others (present in table and present in `List<Keyword>`) should remain untouched to lessen the overhead.

Comment: Do you have easy access to a list of what is currently in the database? So you could just removes the ones no longer there and add the new ones. It may be worth it to just query what is currently there just to be able to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. it should remove ProductKeywords that are not present in the new List collection anymore but still in the table,
> 2. as well as add new ProductKeywords that are not present in the table yet, but in the List.

These are your two operations; simply do them separately.

```
List<Keyword> existingKeywordsForProduct = ...;
List<Keyword> newKeywordsForProduct = ...;

var keywordsToRemove = existingKeywordsForProduct.Except(newKeywordsForProduct);
var keywordsToAdd = newKeywordsForProduct.Except(existingKeywordsForProduct);
```

If the existing keywords is going to be reasonably small then you'll want to pull them all into a list and use LINQ to Objects to do the `Except` calls.  If the list will be very large then it would be better to keep it as an `IQueryable<Keyword>` and do the two round trips so that the `Except` calls can be done on the DB end.

Comment: Hmm okay, so I was hoping to do this in one step... But apparently the most efficient and most clean way is splitting this up.. Thanks!